# .net core bot DI error Unable to resolve service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, botframework

I'm am trying to follow [Microsofts documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs) how to add LUIS to my bot
so I created a `BotServices` class and in `Startup.cs` I am adding it to my service collection

```
    var connectedServices = new BotServices(botConfig);
    services.AddSingleton<BotServices>(sp => connectedServices);
```

and then I am injecting it into my `MyBot` class

```
  public MyBot(BotServices botServices)
```

but I get this error

`System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'BotServices' while attempting to activate 'MyBot'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)`

Comment: I believe you need an interface to register your DI Singleton. Something like `service.AddSingleton<IBotService, BotService>` might do the trick.

Comment: I tried but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

As you are instantiating the object yourself have you tried doing the following:

```
var connectedServices = new BotServices(botConfig);
services.AddSingleton<BotServices>(connectedServices);
```

i.e no need for the factory lambda which you have now (which is picking up a the local variable pointing to your instance ... maybe causes issues...

Comment: Tried but it didn't help

Comment: Just in case have you tried: services.AddSingleton<BotServices>(new BotServices(botConfig));

Comment: I guess you have also registered services.AddScoped<MyBot>();

Comment: I got the problem but I still didn't resolve it. the issue is with service being add in  the `services.AddBot<IBot>()` call. I think I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0):

the problem with my code was that I registered the `BotServices` in the `services.AddBot<IBot>` call like this

**Didn't work:**

```
   services.AddBot<MyBot>(options =>
       {
          var botConfig = BotConfiguration.Load(botFilePath ?? @".\MyBot.bot", secretKey);
          services.AddSingleton(sp => botConfig ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"The .bot config file could not be loaded. ({botConfig})"));
          var connectedServices = new BotServices(botConfig);
          services.AddSingleton<BotServices>(sp => connectedServices);
       }
```

I did it like this because 'botConfig' variable is defined there by default when created with the empty bot template so I moved it out  and it works! (but I still can't explain why it shouldn't work)

**Works**

```
      var botConfig = BotConfiguration.Load(botFilePath ?? @".\MyBot.bot", secretKey);
      services.AddSingleton(sp => botConfig ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"The .bot config file could not be loaded. ({botConfig})"));
      var connectedServices = new BotServices(botConfig);
      services.AddSingleton<BotServices>(sp => connectedServices);
      services.AddBot<MyBot>(options =>
       {
           //all the bot configuration code
       }
```